Targeting specialized skills
I am trying to figure out how to replace 'skills' that immediately follow 'skills-specialization'. Here is what the data looks like. At least the column I am interested in.
Data:



group




skills


skills


skills


skills


skills


skills


skills


skills


skills-specialization


skills


skills


skills


job profile


job description



Here is what I've done so far. But as you can see, it only replaced two skills.
# Define the data
data = [("skills",), ("skills",), ("skills",), ("skills",), ("skills",), 
        ("skills",), ("skills",), ("skills",), ("skills-specialization",), 
        ("skills",), ("skills",), ("skills",), ("job profile",), ("job description",)]

# Create a DataFrame named 'df'
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["group"])

# Add a new column 'partition' indicating presence of "skills-specialization"
df = df.withColumn("partition", F.when(F.col("group") == "skills-specialization", 1).otherwise(0))

# Assign row numbers within each partition
windowSpec = Window.orderBy(F.monotonically_increasing_id())
df = df.withColumn("row_num", F.row_number().over(windowSpec))

# Create a new column 'replace' to mark rows where "skills" follows "skills-specialization"
df = df.withColumn("replace", F.when((F.col("group") == "skills") & (F.lag(F.col("group")).over(windowSpec) == "skills-specialization"), "skills-specialization").otherwise(F.col("group")))

# Update 'replace' column for all rows after the first "skills"
df = df.withColumn("replace", F.when(F.col("replace") == "skills-specialization", "skills-specialization").otherwise(F.col("replace")))

# Select the updated 'replace' column and drop temporary columns
df = df.select("replace").drop("partition", "row_num")

# Display the DataFrame
df.display()


My result:



group




skills


skills


skills


skills


skills


skills


skills


skills


skills-specialization


skills-specialization


skills


skills


job profile


job description



My goal is to get something like this:
End goal:



group




skills


skills


skills


skills


skills


skills


skills


skills


skills-specialization


skills-specialization


skills-specialization


skills-specialization


job profile


job description




There are probably more than one approach to solve it, but that's something that I would do:
windowSpec = Window.orderBy(F.monotonically_increasing_id())
    
# Add a new column 'partition' indicating presence of "skills-specialization" (as the start point) or "job profile" (as the end point)
df = df.withColumn("partition", F.when(F.col("group") == "skills-specialization", 1).otherwise(F.when(F.col("group") == "job profile", 1).otherwise(0)))

# With the sum function I am managing some cumulative count:
df = df.withColumn('partition',  F.sum('partition').over(windowSpec))

# Finally, set "skills-specialization" on the rows where partition is "1"
df = df.withColumn("new_group", F.when(F.col("partition") == 1, "skills-specialization").otherwise(F.col("group")))

As you can see in the code, I wanted to label the start and end point of what I am going to replace. With the "Sum" function I will get:

0: on the first part, the group of "skills"
1: on the second part, that I will try to replace with "skills-specialization"
2: the rest of values that I don't want alter/replace

So, the last line just replace (or in this case creates a new column) with the valid groups by replacing the value only in the section labeled as "1" from the partition column.
